# cron output into a file

Tags: logging, cron

**Setup:**

In my gcp vm instance, I have following cron jobs:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron/mycron.php init >> /var/log/myjob 2>&1
```

The `mycron.php` has a simple function

```
if (!empty($argv[1])) {        
    switch ($argv[1]){
    case 'init':
        cron_test();
        break;
    }
}
function cron_test() {
    $time = date(DATE_RFC822, time());
    write_log("Start:" . $time);   //outputs debug to my own log file   
};
```

However, I was not getting any response and I needed a way of viewing the error log:

**What I did:**

So, in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, I removed `#` in `cron.* /var/log/cron.log` to get the log.

In the `cron.log` I was getting the following log:

```
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` earlier).
```

So, I installed `sudo apt-get install postfix`and selected `no configuration`.

Now I am getting the following...

```
mysite CRON[31304]: (mysite) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/cron/mycron.php init >> /var/log/myjob 2>&1)
mysite CRON[31305]: (mysite) MAIL (mailed 64 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

**What I am trying to figure out:**

I can see the the cronjob is running, but the actual function that I want to run isn't. 
I am trying to view the error (or output) in the log file instead of getting an email about it.

What can I do to get the actual error or output log in a file instead of email?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using bash or shell?

Comment: It's running shell.

Comment: you can either add `#!bin/bash` to your crontab file or use `>>& /var/log/myjob` in case of shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need to view the error log for cron job:

1. Remove # in the cron in the rsyslog

   - Can access the `rsyslog.conf` via `sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.conf
2. Install postfix: `sudo apt-get install postfix` and select `local only` and click next for all
3. in the `crontab -e`, choose a file you want the log to go to:

   Such as `/var/log/user.log`, and change the permission of the file to

   ```
     sudo chmod 775 -R /var/log
     sudo chmod 664 /var/log/user.log
   ```

Then when the cron runs, it will output any issues to the file.